# Laravel 5.1 querying a database with millions of records

Tags: php, mysql, memcached, laravel-5.1

I have a product database with close to 3 million records.  I am writing a webservice to query the db.  The output will be assigned to an array in the client for string matching (exprience similar to you start type ipod in google's search box).   Any suggestions on how can I optimize the query or cache it in such a way that new cache is created only upon the product refresh.   The product DB will be refreshed every week with new products which means the number of records will grow over time.

Comment: how can we help if don't even see the query? You're asking us to tune up a formula 1 car without showing us the car with it's specification

Comment: I would not use a DB for such huge records. Did you try something like ElasticSearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to search by product description in any part of string (LIKE '%string%' query), I would recommend storing unique descriptions in another table with FULL TEXT INDEX, updating it every week (if needed). So when user starts typing we use this table to output suggestions.

When user hits one description we search this description in product table -> so we need adding INDEX on description column in product table.

If you need only match by starting phrase (LIKE 'string%' query), you can simply put INDEX on description column of product table.

Comment: Sam, wouldn't the full index still cause the server load?

Comment: @JotiBasi it needs benchmarking and depends on data size, hardware and load. If your mysql caches queries than it can be slow at the start while there is nothing in cache. If you can allow some delay for keypress event, so there won't be a query on each pressed key, and you haven't got huge amount of requests every second, then it will be totally fine